# Solving for $x$ in $y=N\cdot\left(\frac{10}{x}\right)^{-2.6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to confirm my solution of $x$ from 
$$y=N\cdot\left(\frac{10}{x}\right)^{-2.6}$$ 
My answer is:
$$x=\frac{N^{2.6}}{10\cdot y^{2.6}}$$ 
Is this right? How would you solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that
$$
y = N \cdot \left( \dfrac{10}{x} \right)^{-2.6} = N \cdot \left( \dfrac{x}{10} \right)^{2.6}
$$
Next, divide both sides by $N$:
$$
\dfrac{y}{N} = \left( \dfrac{x}{10} \right)^{2.6}
$$
Now exponentiate with $\frac{1}{2.6}$ to get
$$
\left( \dfrac{y}{N} \right)^{\frac{1}{2.6}} = \dfrac{x}{10}
$$
Finally, multiply by $10$:
$$
10 \cdot \left( \dfrac{y}{N} \right)^{\frac{1}{2.6}} = x
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $$y = N \cdot (\frac{10}{x})^{-2.6}$$

Then,

$$y \cdot (\frac{10}{x})^{2.6} = N$$

$$ y \cdot 10 ^{2.6} = N \cdot x^{2.6}$$

$$ (y \cdot 10^{2.6})^{1/2.6} = (N \cdot x^{2.6})^{1/2.6}$$

$$ y^{1/2.6} \cdot 10 = N^{1/2.6} \cdot x$$

$$ x = y^{1/2.6} \cdot 10 \cdot N^{-1/2.6} = (\frac{y}{N})^{1/2.6} \cdot 10 $$